# Does improvement on regularity implies compactness?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $M$ be a compact metric space and $\mathcal C^0(M)=\{f:M\to\mathbb R; f\ \text{is continous}\}$. Let $T:\mathcal C^0(M)\to \mathcal C^0(M)$ be a bounded linear transformation.

Suppose that for every $f\in\mathcal C^0(M)$ we have that $Tf$ is $1/2$-Hölder. Does this imply that $T$ is compact?

---

It is clear that if $ | T f | _ {\mathcal C^{1/2} (M)}\leq K$ for some $ K> 0$ for every $\| f\|_{\mathcal C^0(M)}\leq 1$, then Arzela-Ascoli implies the result. However, I believe that this is not generally true. Also, I am not able to imply that $T(B(0,1))$ is equicontinuous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$C^{1/2}(M)$ is a Banach space. Since the norm on $C^{1/2}(M)$ is stronger than the norm on $C^0(M)$, one sees that $T$ is closed as an operator from $C^0(M)$ to $C^{1/2}(M)$. Thus, it is bounded by the closed graph theorem. In particular, we indeed have $\sup_{\|f\| \leq 1} |Tf|_{C^{1/2}(M)} < \infty$. The remainder is just Arzelà–Ascoli theorem, as you already mentioned.